# Finding time difference between two dates up to years

Tags: android, algorithm, date

```
private String getTimeDiff(Date D1, Date D2){
    ...
    return diffString;
}
```

I want to create a function which takes two java.util.date objects and returns difference in following manner:

--> If time difference is more than a year, it should return just year difference (like 5 years)

--> If it's less than a year but more than a month, it it should return just month difference (like 2 months)

--> And so on for Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds

**This will be used in a well populated listview items so I'm looking for a solution which would give the result with minimum processing.**

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long t1 = d1.getTime();
long t2 = d2.getTime()
long diff = Math.abs(t1-t2);
int years = diff %(365*24*60*60*1000);
if(years >0){
  return ""+years+" years";
}
int months = diff%(30*24*60*60*1000);
if(months>0){
  return ""+months+" months";
}
```

And repeat for weeks, days, hours etc.  Use named constants for the lengths, I was just being lazy.

Comment: Nope, Java long is 64 bits (so max_long is 2^63-1).  Common C++ implementations use 32 bit longs, but even that isn't forced (in C++ the only rule is long >=int >=short >= char, the actual sizes aren't forced to certain values).

Comment: Yeah, I just found that out. Thanks for the answer